# How to bind to a specific ou in ldap

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I want to be able to allow a single ou in Active directory to have authentication access to an internal website of my company. Please help as I have wasted too much time on it.
This is what I have got so far:

```
$domain ='ab.cd.ef.gh.ij';
        $host='xxx.xxx.xx.x';
        $ds = ldap_connect($host); //has to be domain or hostname
        ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
        ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

        if($ds)
        {

            $bind=ldap_bind($ds,$name, $pass);
            if($bind)
            {
                $_SESSION['status'] = 'authorized';
                header("location: index.php");
            } else return "Please enter correct username and password.";
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works perfect if you want to allow one ou to have access to a login system :

```
$domain ='ab.cd.ef.gh.ij';
        $host='xxx.xxx.xx.x';
        $connect = ldap_connect($host); //has to be domain or hostname
        ldap_set_option($connect, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
        ldap_set_option($connect, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
        $dn = "OU=something,OU=something,OU=something,OU=something,DC=ab,DC=cd,DC=ef,DC=gh,DC=ij";
        $search = "CN=$name";  

        if($connect)
        {
            $bind=ldap_bind($connect,$name, $pass);
            if($bind)
            {
                $sr=ldap_search($connect, $dn, $search);
                $data = ldap_get_entries($connect, $sr);
                for ($i=0; $i<$data["count"]; $i++) 
                {
                     $user = $data[$i]["dn"] ;
                }
                 if($user =="CN=$name,OU=something,OU=something,OU=something,OU=something,DC=ab,DC=cd,DC=ef,DC=gh,DC=ij")
                {
                    $_SESSION['status'] = 'authorized';
                    header("location: index.php");
                }else
                {
                header("location:lost.html");
                }

            } else return "Please enter correct username and password.";
        }
```

The only down side to this is that the username and the common name has to be the same for this to work.

Happy Coding